# how to over come while sending a html content which having special characters to asp.net backend using jquery ajax post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using CKEditor in a ASP.Net page to render another whole page which contain HTML Report inside the CKEditor.After rendering i will do what ever the changes i need. after that if i try to save it saving fine.

While saving if type special characters like /,@ then it is giving error.
input string is not in correct format.

I want to save the whole content as it is.If i need to edit that data again i need to render the data what i saved with that special Characters(/,@ like these)....

Suggest me any one to overcome this situation.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just give a try by keeping `<system.web>
     <pages validateRequest="false"> 
</system.web>` in webconfig

Comment: if i use this,it will effect to all pages.but i dont want to affect whole project pages.Can i make any condition for the particular method in that page.

Comment: you can give in the particular aspx page at the top of the page directive

Answer (score 0):

I think the right way would be to send data in [url encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) format or better to replace special characters with ASCII codes.